# Simplest method to swap an image on a website every 12 hours using PHP

Tags: php, html

I haven't coded in a while and I'm trying to find the easiest solution to this problem.

I have 20+ images on the server (labelled 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, etc.) and I'm using PHP to render three of them to my website at a time.

All I want is to make it so every twelve hours a new image replaces one of the old images. So for example it starts by rendering images 1, 2 and 3 and after twelve hours it switches to 2, 3 and 4.

What's the best way to achieve this effect?

Comment: You can reload the page every 12 hours and send next images. Is this what you need?

Comment: Check the time. If it's between 00:00 and 12:00, use the first set. Otherwise, use the second set.

Comment: Check the current date and time with [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: So, if I load to your webpage now, it shows 1,2,3 and if I load in 12 hours, it should show 2,3,4. Am I right?

Comment: @ATOzTOA That is correct.

Comment: No need to use a cron job. Just have it check to see what time it is when the script is loaded. If 12 hours have passed since the last image was loaded, increment. If 24 hours have passed, increment twice. etc

Comment: But where do I store when the script was loaded? It has to be based on the server. A session variable won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in simple PHP (since you mentioned PHP).

```
$numOfImages = 20;
$unit = date('j') * 2; // Day of the month, doubled to simulate chunks of 12 hours.
if (date('G') < 12) { // Hours 0 - 23
    $unit--;
}

$image1 = $unit % $numOfImages;
$image2 = ($unit + 1) % $numOfImages;
$image3 = ($unit + 2) % $numOfImages;

var_dump($image1);
var_dump($image2);
var_dump($image3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a cronjob, you can use the `time()` function and use the `mod` power for shift the images seen every 12 hours.

Try this script

```
$now = time(); // you can simulate adding 12 hours +3600*12

$base = round( $now/(3600*12) ); // this number change every 12 hours

$n_images = 20; // number of your images

$start_from = $base % $n_images; // start from $start_from image

// loop for get your 4 images (3,4,5,6 or 4,5,6,7 or ,18,19,20,1,2 etc.)
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    $image = ($start_from+$i) % $n_images + 1;
    echo "get image " . $image.".jpg<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to write php script which will do replacing and which will be executed by cron every 12 hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cron job to run a script that would increment the index on the image URL.

`php * */12 * * * root/to/updateImage.php`

The in the update image script just change a value in the database that refers to which image you are currently using.

Comment: Trying to avoid having to write a cron job. Is there a second option?

Comment: You should mention that in your question just so people know that the answer does not use a cron when they find this page :) You could have the page check the time when a user opens the page.  Have a 'start' time that is hard coded from day one, and work out how many hours have passed since this time, divide that number by 12 and use this as the image number in your img `src` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use cron jobs then I would create a symlink "current.jpg" and every 12 hours fire a script which executes a command to change the symlink to another one. Another option is to have a file "img_config.php" with a value:

```
$current_image = 3;
```

and every time cron hits do:

```
include "img_config.php"
$current_nr = (++$current_image)%20+1;
file_put_contents("img_config.php",'$current_image = '.$current_nr.';');
```

Of course you have got many other options like store that in a value in a database.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, select which images to show from a `config file`, which may look like:

```
1.png
2.png
3.png
```

Then write a cron job with a shell script, which will modify the `config file`. You can use `sed` or `awk` for it.

Answer (score 0):

Cron, or a function with this logic on top of your app, if "exact hours" is not a concern:

```
Read content of last_change.txt

If the content *plus* 12 hours *is less than* current time

    Change images

    Put current time to last_change.txt

Done
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with one image which should be chosen from a set of images and I didn't have cron access. So I came up with:

```
function changeStartpageImage() {
    // change the image every x hours
    $hours = 170;
    $fileinfo = stat("images/startseite/startseitenbild.jpg");
    if (time() - $fileinfo['mtime'] < ($hours * 60* 60)) {
        return;
    }

    $handler = opendir("images/startseite/");
    $results = array();

    while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
        if (substr($file, 0, 1) != "." && $file != "startseitenbild.jpg" ) {
            $results[] = $file;
        }
    }
    $newFile = $results[array_rand($results)];
    copy("images/startseite/".$newFile, "images/startseite/startseitenbild.jpg");

    closedir($handler);
}
```

I think you can elaborate on this example and make it even nicer, but it is a possibility to deal with the problem without having to deal with Cronjobs :-)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't run a cron. Here is how I would do it:

```
$num_images = 20;
$images_display = 3;
$hours = 12;
$time_block = 60 * 60 * $hours;
$time_now = strtotime('now');
$block_num = floor($time_now / $time_block) % $num_images;

$images = array();
for($x=1;$x<=$images_display;$x++) {
        $image_num = $block_num + $x;
        if($image_num > $num_images) $image_num = $image_num % $num_images;
        $images[$x] = $image_num . '.png';
}
```

Comment: This is assuming that files are named 1.png, 2.png, etc... Also you could easily make `$num_images` dynamic by scanning a specific directory for number of files.